# Three.js FXAA background transparency

Tags: three.js

Created a simple scene with a cube in it.  Able to see the color of the containing element, (body), in the background.

Added an FXAA shader and the antialiasing works well.  However the background is now black, so can no longer see the color of the background container.

Added the following code:

var target = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(512, 512);

var composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer, target );

in order to set the effect composer render target format to THREE.RGBAFormat, rather than the default THREE.RGBFormat.

This makes the background work properly, but then there are black and white edges around the cube and the antialiasing does not look very good.

Repeated the above but used the Sepia shader instead of the FXAA shader.  This works correctly.  The cube looks sepia and the background containing element color is correct.

Are there any workarounds to allow antialiasing and transparent background?

Thanks for any help

Comment: can you create a fiddle? or show some screenshots of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I read your issue and there seems to be a good source that can solve or at least lead you down the right path. Go check out: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2125

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much user2529011 for your suggestion and sorry for the late reply, I checked the link but this did not solve the problem. Also thanks guygood for your response.

Comment: I shall create some examples and post them here, though it may take a week or two.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21056080/2482976

The FXAA needed to be updated to handle the transparent background